# Django admin manage ForeignKey in Add/Edit form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

In my django app i have this model:

```
class temp_test_keywords(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    main_id = models.ForeignKey(temp_main, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tm_ttk')
    test_id = models.ForeignKey(temp_case, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tc_ttk')
    key_id = models.ForeignKey(temp_keywords, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tk_ttk')
    key_val = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Value')
    key_group = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Group')
    #Fields for API permissions
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='ttestkey_owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="API Owner")
```

In admin.py i create the relative `ModelAdmin` for manage list, add and edit options:

```
class temp_test_keywordsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_filter = ('main_id__descr', 'test_id__descr')
    list_display = ('get_main_id', 'get_test_id', 'key_id', 'key_val', 'key_group')

    def get_main_id(self, obj):
        return obj.main_id.descr

    def get_test_id(self, obj):
        return obj.test_id.descr

    get_main_id.short_description = 'Main Template'
    get_main_id.admin_order_field = 'main_id__descr'

    get_test_id.short_description = 'Test Case'
    get_test_id.admin_order_field = 'test_id__descr'
```

Now when i view m data in `changelist_view` template all was done, but when i try to add or edit a record in my test_id field i see the object (`test_case_obj(1)`) and not the `descr` field.
How can i manage `ForeignKey` for point to a specific field also in add/edit admin form?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `__str__` method in your models for that. For eg:

```
class temp_case(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.descr)
```

In case you want some other representation for your object on admin panel, you can create a custom form and define the custom representation for the `ModelChoiceField` as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

The docs suggest to *subclass* **`ModelChoiceField`** and and override `label_from_instance` method.

Hope it helps.